# How to use Z3 with C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, z3

I want to use Z3 with C++, and I followed the installation guide - [Building Z3 on Windows using Visual Studio Command Prompt](https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3#building-z3-on-windows-using-visual-studio-command-prompt).

I built it successfully, then I also added the build path to the system path. However, I still got an error when I was trying to run the [example.cpp](https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/blob/master/examples/c%2B%2B/example.cpp) file. The error says `[Error] z3++.h: No such file or directory`. Can anyone tell me is there any other configuration I need to do after building Z3 using Visual Studio Command Prompt successfully in order to run Z3 with c++?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you add the `z3\src\api\c++` and `z3\src\api` path to your include directories when compiling?

If you're working with a Visual Studio project, you need to add it in the project properties under "C++" -> "Additional Include Directories".

When compiling manually using `cl`, you can use the `/I[path]` command line parameter (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/73f9s62w.aspx).

You will also have to add the `z3.lib` to your compilation once you actually start using the `z3` API in your code, lest you receive `undefined reference` errors. In Visual Studio, that's "Linker" -> "Additional Dependencies" and optionally "Additional Library Directories" if you're using a relative path to the library.

In my environment, the following command line gets your example program compiled: `cl example.cpp /I C:\tools\z3\z3-master\src\api\c++ /I C:\tools\z3\z3-master\src\api C:\tools\z3\z3-master\build\libz3.lib`

Comment: Thanks, I solved the "No such file or directory" for z3++.h problem. But I still have many LIN2019 errors after adding libz3.lib. Do you know what's the problem?

Comment: I first add 'C:\z3-master\build' to the 'Additional Library Directories', then add 'libz3.lib' to the 'Additional Dependencies'. But it still has so many LNK2019 errors.

Comment: If Visual Studio doesn't complain that it can't find the library file you specified and instead shows `unresolved external symbol` errors, that probably means that the DLL was compiled with a different platform setting than is configured in your project.

Did you compile Z3 with the "x64 Native Tools" Visual Studio Command Prompt? If so, you need to make sure that your project build is configured as "x64" in the configuration manager: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9yb4317s.aspx