# compilation and execution command for z3 in cpp?

Tags: c++, z3, smt

```
#include<z3++.h>  
#include<iostream>
#include"mainProj.cpp"
using namespace std;
using namespace z3;


int main()
{   context c;
    tactic t = tactic(c, "bit-blast");
    expr x = c.bv_const("x", 16);
    expr y = c.bv_const("y", 16);
    expr z = c.bv_const("z", 16);
    goal g(c);
    g.add(x == y + z);
    return 0;
}
```

I am supposed to execute the following code. What is the command for compilation and execution?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use Z3 with C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51993350/how-to-use-z3-with-c)

Comment: No. I have done this before. I just forgot the command to compile the file.

Comment: If you are not using an Ide, that depends on what kind of compiler you use. Check these [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11365850/run-c-in-command-prompt-windows) for details

Comment: I am using Visual Code Studio on linux. and the command was something like 
" myProj.cpp -lz3 " but this one is not working.

Answer (score 0):

The compilation for my program is 
" g++ myProj.cpp -lz3 "
Hope it is useful

Comment: Do you know what g++ is?

Comment: g++ command is a compiler invocation command, which is used for preprocessing, compilation, assembly and linking of source code to generate an executable file